# Necesito ayuda para mostrar algunos datos de una consulta. ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente consulta anidada con subselects

```
SELECT PEDIDO.ARTICULO , PEDIDO.CANTIDAD_SERVIDA , PEDIDO.LOTE_ARTICULO, 
  PEDIDO.FECHA_VENCIMIENTO, MIN(BULTO.NUMERO_LINE),
  BULTO.CODIGO_CONTENEDOR , SUM(CANTIDAD_EN_CONTENEDOR)
FROM
    (SELECT PED_LN.ARTICULO,
    SUM(CANTIDAD_SERVIDA) AS CANTIDAD_SERVIDA,
    PED_LN.NUMERO_PEDIDO AS NUMERO_PEDIDO,
    PED_LN.LOTE_ARTICULO,
    PED_LN.FECHA_VENCIMIENTO AS FECHA_VENCIMIENTO
    FROM XXOSI_OMPEDLN_SIS_IN_T PED_LN
    WHERE 
    PED_LN.NUMERO_PEDIDO = 'I-99558462321' 
    and PED_LN.CANTIDAD_SERVIDA > 0
  GROUP BY PED_LN.ARTICULO, PED_LN.NUMERO_PEDIDO, PED_LN.LOTE_ARTICULO, 
  PED_LN.FECHA_VENCIMIENTO) PEDIDO
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT BUL_LN.ARTICULO AS ARTICULO, 
 BUL_LN.CODIGO_CONTENEDOR AS CODIGO_CONTENEDOR, 
 SUM(BUL_LN.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD_EN_CONTENEDOR, 
 BUL_LN.NUMERO_PEDIDO AS NUMERO_PEDIDO, 
 BUL_LN.LINEA_EN_PEDIDO AS NUMERO_LINE,
 BUL_LN.LOTE
 FROM XXOSI_OMBULLN_SIS_IN_T BUL_LN
 WHERE 
 BUL_LN.NUMERO_PEDIDO = 'I-99558462321'
 GROUP BY BUL_LN.ARTICULO, BUL_LN.CODIGO_CONTENEDOR, BUL_LN.NUMERO_PEDIDO, 
 BUL_LN.LINEA_EN_PEDIDO, BUL_LN.LOTE) BULTO
 ON PEDIDO.ARTICULO = BULTO.ARTICULO 
  AND   PEDIDO.LOTE_articulo = BULTO.LOTE
  group by PEDIDO.ARTICULO, PEDIDO.CANTIDAD_SERVIDA, PEDIDO.LOTE_ARTICULO,  
  PEDIDO.FECHA_VENCIMIENTO, BULTO.CODIGO_CONTENEDOR,BULTO.LOTE 
  ORDER BY PEDIDO.ARTICULO;
```

### El problema

Al hacer lo siguiente **AND PEDIDO.LOTE_articulo = BULTO.LOTE** solo me traerá  los productos que sean iguales en las dos tablas. y los demás productos me los deja en null, como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen.

[image: SELECT IGUALADO]

Esto es por que no tienen data en el campo **LOTE_ARTICULO**, entonces 
lo que necesito es aparte de traer los que sean iguales en las dos tablas 
que me muestre la información de los que no tienen información en el campo **LOTE_ARTICULO**, esta información si existe, pero como igualo lo que tiene una tabla con la otra y algunos productos no tienen data en el campo **LOTE_ARTICULO** me deja los datos como null.

Si a la query le saco el **AND PEDIDO.LOTE_articulo = BULTO.LOTE** y otros campos de la consulta para que no se habra la query me deberia mostrar algo como esto:

[image: Consulta con data]

Comment: Ya probaste usando inner join en vez de left join porque por eso te muestra los nulos

Comment: @Raul Cacacho, Si probé pero nada aun.

Comment: pero con inner join como te muestra los datos?

Comment: @Raul Cacacho, me muestra los datos que están en las dos tablas, si te das cuenta en la primera foto que indico mas arriba hay 3 registros que no muestran datos nulos, esos mismos 3 registros me muestra usando el inner join, lo que necesito yo es algo parecido a lo que muestro en la segunda foto. lo que pasa que al agregar el campo **LOTE_ARTICULO** y **FECHA_VENCIMIENTO** se habré la query, mi necesidad es que esos 3 registros no se dupliquen de, tal manera que pueda mostrar esos 3 registros que te comento y ademas mostrar los datos de los demás campos que los escupe nulos.